# Invariance of geometric shapes under basis transformations.

Tags: geometry, tensors

If I describe some geometric shape (like a square in $\Bbb R^2$, or a torus in $\Bbb R^3$) and then change the basis which I use to describe it, does this have any relation to the invariance of tensors under basis transformations? I understand that a torus for instance doesn't have a set of components in the same way that a vector does, but the basis which is used to describe it doesn't influence its actual structure. Is there a term for this in the same way we call objects who's components transform predictably "tensors"?

I am studying physics not mathematics so forgive any egregious misunderstanding of geometry.

Comment: Things that are invariant under X transformations are often called "X geometry". A change of basis is a transformation of Euclidean space, so we'd call the study of things invariant (or covariant or contravariant) under basis transformations "Euclidean geometry." This is my understanding of it anyway. Maybe someone else can think of more to say.